Dataframe - Select the minimum set of rows to cover all possible values of each columns
I'm working on a use-case on which I need to retrieve a minimal sample of rows from a dataframe that contains at least one row for each unique value found in all columns.
A simplified example could be :



ID
A
B
C




1
D
G
X


2
D
G
Y


3
E
G
Y


4
E
H
Y


5
F
I
Z



Here I would like to keep rows with ID 1, 4 and 5, in order to have at least one row with values D, E and F from A; G, H and I from B and X, Y and Z from C. I don't need to have all combinations, only all uniques values from every column:



ID
A
B
C




1
D
G
X


4
E
H
Y


5
F
I
Z



What could be an efficient way to do this?
Thank you

Two questions: (1) Assuming row 3 would be (E, G, D) rather than (E, G, Y), I would also need to include it even though D already appeared in row 1, because it did not appear in column C so far, is this correct? Or, alternatively, can I assume that values are unique within their columns (i.e. value D is unique to column A so cannot appear in column C)? (2) Although the problem is rather a general one and so this aspect is less important, I assume with "Dataframe" you refer to a Pandas Dataframe?

(1) It would also need to be included yes, uniqueness must be considered within each column.
(2) Data are currently within a sql table, but I loaded them in a pandas dataframe to do some first testing yes

Maybe I am overthinking this, but it appears to me primarily as a mathematical problem and only after that as a programming problem. I guess the problem could be reformulated as: Given a set S and n partitions of S – P_1, …, P_n – choose a minimum number of elements from S such that for each subset in each P_i, at least one element is chosen. Here, S are the rows (i.e. each element is a row), n is the number of columns, and each P_i is defined by the unique values of the corresponding column (rows with the same value in the i-th column are in the same subset of P_i). Not sure if this helps.

In particular, I have no idea how to solve this problem efficiently, but maybe someone else has. Maybe it would also be an idea to formulate this as a question on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

My hope was maybe there was a library dedicated to sampling those kind of data, but maybe that case is a bit specific. Thanks for your input, I'll look into the mathemical pov of this.

Sounds like it's a case where there's a greedy algorithm that gives a near-optimal solution and a dynamic programming algorithm that gives the optimal solution.

Having thought a bit more about this, I think I'm going to go with a really-approximate solution by ordering the value of all columns by frequency, picking a random row with the least frequent one, and cycling through all values checking every time if my already selected rows contains that value, and if not adding another randow row (trying to maximize the "new" values it contains) with this value to my subset

Here is what I ended up going with:

Count the number of occurrences of every value in each column, and order those by count asc
Select a random row that contains the least occurring value of all, and add this value and all the others from the selected row into a dictionary
Looping through my ordered list of values, count the number of "new values" for each row that contains the current value of the list the loop is on. Pick the row with the highest number of "new values".
Repeat until all values have been picked

Far from the optimal solution as I'm only minimizing the number of rows on each step, but it's pretty efficient and it gets the job done.
Could have probably gone with a recursive algorithm to test all solutions but I don't have a big requirement on the final set of rows, except it needed all possible values.
Thank you all for inputs, they helped me come up to this solution.

It would be nice if you put the code that you are using to solve the problem

here's a minimal example to get you going.
USING: # (tab separated !)
ID  COLA    COLB    COLC    COLD
1   D   G   X   
2   D   G       K
3   E   G   M   
4   E   H       L
5   F   I   Z   L
6   O   Z       P

#this code
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('input1.csv', sep='\t')

# get the columns - skipping the first
# remove 'nan', then get unique values using 'set' sorted
for col in list(df)[1:]:
    wk=[ member for member in df[col] if not(pd.isnull(member)) == True]
    print(f'{col} {sorted(set(wk))}')

#produces
COLA ['D', 'E', 'F', 'O']
COLB ['G', 'H', 'I', 'Z']
COLC ['M', 'X', 'Z']
COLD ['K', 'L', 'P']

hope this is of some help

I don't think OP's problem is finding the unique elements of each column. Instead, the problem is to find the minimum set of rows, such that each unique element of each column is covered. So, looking at individual columns is not enough.

@simon,  you may well be correct, the post is/was ambiguous afaics , the last sentence ... """ I don't need to have all combinations, only all uniques values from every column.""" is what prompted me to post that, of course the requester can choose to ignore, but thks for the feedback.

As @simon explained, thanks for trying though, sorry the post was a bit ambiguous

@JojoDolo, np, so given the set of data you published in your question, can you post what the expected resulting dataset should be (in a similar table to your initial post) - thks, that'll help (clarify for me at least) ,  additionally, if you've found a solution to post that code. tks

It is already written in the question: Here I would like to keep rows with ID 1, 4 and 5. Also the reason is given: to have at least one row with values D, E and F from A; G, H and I from B and X, Y and Z from C.

@simon, again, thks for your feedback, however, its still not clear to me (english not my first), hence the request. Again, if interpretion ... then a union all of the colums will give a single result of all distinct members across all columns, trivial :  un=list( set(df.COLA) | set(df.COLB) | set(df.COLC) | set(df.COLD) )
un=[mbr for mbr in un if str(mbr) != 'nan']
print( sorted(un) ). again, if the poster would respond to my request ... otherwise i leave this alone. tks

English is not my first language either so sorry if my explanation is not very clear.
I have updated my post with expected result.
To clarify what I'm trying to achieve, I don't want to gather all distinct combinations across all columns (which is what your code will achieve), but I'm trying to gather a subset of rows for which every value from each column will appear at least once.
Let's say I have rows A, B, C; A, B, D and B, B, D, all three have different combinations but if I only select A, B, C and B, B, D, all unique values are selected and I do not need the A, B, D row.

Hope it's clear now.
I'm still working on my solution (posted a really approximate algo on a coment of the other answer), I'll be sure to update the post if the solution is satisfying.

@JojoDolo, np, obviously i'm missing the salient point in your post, so apologies for any time lost. fyi , run the code with your input it produces expected output, but I'll leave others to help now.
